# DuckDNS profile gone after changing name on GitHub

Tags: github

I signed up to DuckDNS using GitHub. The other day, I changed my GitHub name and email and when I logged into DuckDNS my old profile was gone, replaced by a new one. There doesn't seem to be a way to contact them. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem aswell and I've figured out a solution:

1. Rename your GitHub account back to its original name EXACTLY (Including capitalisation)
2. Sign into DuckDNS
3. Take a note of your domain names & their IPs
4. Delete all the domains
5. Rename your GitHub account to the new name
6. Sign out of DuckDNS and then sign back in using GitHub again.
7. Re-create all of your domains with your new account.

It's a bit annoying, but it works at least!